# Should a f:viewParam bound to a bean's property keep its default value when the param is not present?

Tags: jsf, jboss-eap-7

I noticed a difference in behavior starting with JBoss EAP 7.2.

Given the following bean:

```java
@Model
public class MyBean {

    private static final String DEFAULT_FOO = "defaultFoo";

    private String foo = DEFAULT_FOO; // + getter and setter
}
```

and a xhtml page containing:

```xml
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="foo" value="#{myBean.foo}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Prior to JBoss EAP 7.2, a link to that page which does not include the `foo` param will keep the default value for the `MyBean.foo` property. Starting from JBoss EAP 7.2, the same link will set the `MyBean.foo` property to `null`.

I can't decide what the correct behavior really is and whether that change is a regression (which should be corrected at the jboss/mojarra side) or if it's a correction (then I should change my code which expects the default value and is based on a false assumption).

Note: I am using `javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL = true` in my web.xml. As soon as I set it to `false`, the difference disappears.

Comment: Do you know the different JSF versions in both servers? Compared those to see if something changed in the mean time

Comment: And http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/viewParam?foo=test&bar=test seems to have a solution for your problem migration wise... You can configure a default when the param is absent

Comment: JBoss EAP 7.1 uses mojarra 2.2.13 while EAP 7.2 uses 2.3.5. (but I think redhat is using their own build of mojarra which backports some fixes from ulterior versions). After some searching, the problem might be related to https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4550